# Can groups of automorphism over non-isomorphic groups be isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Can two groups of automorphisms over non-isomorphic groups be isomorphic?
If $G$ and $G'$ are non-isomorphic groups and $\text{Aut}(G)$ and $\text{Aut}(G')$ be their group of automorphisms, then can they be isomorphic to each other or not?

Answer (score 5):

Aut$(\Bbb Z_3)$ and Aut$(\Bbb Z_4)$ are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: An infinite example of such groups: $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})$ and $\operatorname{Aut}( \mathbb{Z}/2p \mathbb{Z})$ for prime $p$.

Comment: And What is their automorphism?

Comment: @keshradha the trivial one and inversion.

Comment: What is inversion?

Answer (score 1):

A non-abelian example, $Aut(Q) \cong S_4 \cong Aut(S_4)$. Here $Q$ is the quaternion group of $8$ elements.

Comment: Are they always same...can u give an example where they are not same but isomorphic

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Two isomorphic groups with non-isomorphic automorphism groups? Those do not exist!

Comment: I mean two non-isomorphic groups whose automorphism groups are only isomorphic they should not be same...like ur example both are $S_4$

Comment: OK (also have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586471/show-that-if-gcdg-h-1-then-textautg-times-h-cong-textau), let $p \geq 5$ be prime. Then $Aut(Q \times C_p) \cong S_4 \times C_{p-1} \cong Aut(S_4 \times C_p)$. Now you have three non-isomorphic non-abelian groups.

Answer (score 0):

As a more complicated example, we have $\operatorname{Aut}(C_2\times C_8)\cong C_2\times D_8$ and
$$\operatorname{Aut}(C_2\times C_{12})\cong\operatorname{Aut}(C_3)\times\operatorname{Aut}(C_2\times C_4)=C_2\times D_8.$$