# If $\mathrm{Aut}(G \times H) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G) \times \mathrm{Aut}(H)$, then is $\mathrm{gcd}(\left| G \right|, \left| H \right|) = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gcd-and-lcm, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I know that the converse is true, i.e., if $\mathrm{gcd}(\left| G \right|, \left| H \right|) = 1$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(G \times H) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G) \times \mathrm{Aut}(H)$. It is said [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/586471).

My question is: Is the converse true? I.e., If $\mathrm{Aut}(G \times H) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G) \times \mathrm{Aut}(H)$, then is $\mathrm{gcd}(\left| G \right|, \left| H \right|) = 1$?

There is no work done for this and this is just a curious question.

Comment: I doubt it. If $G$ and $H$ are simple, I believe this is true if neither is isomorphic to a subgroup of the other. In particular, if $G$ and $H$ are simple and neither of $|G|$ or $|H|$ divides the other, then it is true, I believe.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, leave a like!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420884/562051 I believe this post would be helpful